# Jenkins Github organization scan a team

Tags: jenkins, github, github-api, jenkins-github-plugin

We have a Github organization, which is broken into teams.
I want to use Jenkins github plugin to just scan my teams folder, is this possible?
So far I can only get it to scan the whole org which has thousands of repos in it, or scan my user which also picks up other repos outside the team.

I have tried scanning for `<ORG>/teams/<TEAM>` but Jenkins seems to think that is a user and looks in the user api rather than org.

I know I could use a repo name filter, but currently the repos dont have a standard enough name to do that on and renaming them would be a pain as all links and clone would need updating.

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: I was wondering if you found any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and after doing some digging I think I've found the solution. After you setup your Organization Folder within Jenkins, if you go into the config, then into the Repository Sources section, there is a filter you can add called GitHub Team Slug. This filter allows you to enter your team slug name which is typically just the name found in the URL. It should filter out all repos that are not associated with your team within the org. I attached an image showing what the filter looks like within Jenkins. Reach out if you have any questions! [image]